# How do I delay the execution of an Azure function after it fails?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using an Azure Function (written in C#) that is triggered when there is a new message on the storage queue. The function is calling an external web-service to process the message, and when the external service is responding, everything is OK.

The problem is when the external web-site is down, and the web-client gives an exception (without a try/catch block around it). What happens then is that the function is retried (by azure) 5 times, with less than a second between each attempt. As you can imagine, the web service will  probably still be down for all 5 attempts which will make azure move the message to the "poison"-queue.

Is it possible to configure the the amount of time it waits before retrying, or do i need to set up another azure function that runs once a minute to check the poison-queue for messages that then needs to be recreated in the normal queue?

Answer (score 4):

We don't currently expose a way for you to configure the visibility timeout for failed messages. It is currently hardcoded to `TimeSpan.Zero` as you've noticed. I agree with you that we should allow this to be customized. I've logged an issue in our public repo with more details [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/844).

Comment: Thank you for creating the issue. You say something about creating a custom queue processor, but i guess that is only available for webjobs and not azure functions?

Comment: Yes, that is a more involved, lower level customizability that is not available in Functions.

Comment: @mathewc I see that the github issue is closed and [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#queues) allows settting `visibilityTimeout`. But that is a fixed time interval. What if I want to implement exponential back-off?

Answer (score 0):

> The function is calling an external web-service to process the message, and when the external service is responding, everything is OK.

Why not signal the service status with a queue message.

```
Function is triggered
        \  /
         \/
Do we have a message in service-status queue?
        \  /
         \/    
Wait 30 seconds before making web-service call / else call it right away.
        \  /
         \/
Can't reach web-service? -> Drop message in service-status queue.
```

If you have multiple instances of that Function App you'll need to signal with either a durable file on storage or an entry in Table Storage.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, the idea is good. The problem however is that Azure bills these functions by the second, so it will be very expensive to run a Thread.Sleep(30000) inside it.

Comment: Then don't wait 30 seconds. Quit. You won't drop the message since you didn't delete it. It will become visible again in `visibility_timeout`. The order of messages in the queue will be screwed, but if you can tolerate that i don't see any other downside.

Comment: Maybe i am misunderstanding you, but if i just quit the function, azure will think that the message is successfully processed and it will be gone forever. I have not yet discovered how i can change/set the visibility-timeout from within an azure function.

Comment: That shouldn't happen unless the Function Queue trigger works very differently vs Storage Queue SDK - See "De-queue the next message" - https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues.md#de-queue-the-next-message -- _To finish removing the message from the queue, you must also call DeleteMessage._

Comment: That is not how azure functions work. You do not call the storage SDK manually, it is done for you. Take a look at this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4dc75974-4841-41e4-a3d9-7a6ce46fe3b6/azure-webjob-queuetrigger-how-deletemessage-after-get-it?forum=windowsazuredata

Comment: Your messages will eventually reach a high enough de-queue count property they will be sent to the Deadletter queue.. you will need to find a way around that if you quit execution midway through.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123988/discussion-between-espo-and-evilsnobu).

Comment: Ah yes i remember this, just throw an exception, don't quit gracefully. The Functions SDK will pick that signal and `.DeleteMessage()` won't get called. Try it out.

Comment: Please read the question again, that is what i am doing (throwing an exception). I am asking how to increase the delay before azure retries it again.

Comment: _the web-client gives an exception_ you have to agree with me it's not very clear there if you handle that or not.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up handling the *visibilityTimeout* parameter "manually": we do not use output bindings but schedule the message in the queue for later processing using the Azure storage SDK.

See https://github.com/teamdigitale/digital-citizenship-functions/blob/master/lib/utils/azure_queues.ts#L86

```
 queueService.updateMessage(
        queueName,
        queueMessage.id,
        queueMessage.popReceipt,
        visibilityTimeoutSec,
        err => {
          context.done( err );
        }
      );
```

This let us plug an exponential backoff strategy for reties without putting the process to sleep.