# Azure Function Queue trigger: how to set time delay for dequeue message

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-queues

I have an Azure Function which listens to azure queue and, for example, something wrong. It re-adds a message to the queue again. But after 5 times message will be moved to poison queue.

I want to re-add a message to queue with a delay. For example, retry thru 1 hour. Because my Azure Function works with external resource, which can be unavailable for now. I don't want to do retry 5 times during 10 seconds at all, I want to retry after 1 hour. Of course, I write my own implementation of it, but probably this feature already exists.

Comment: these might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50817971/how-to-implement-exponential-backoff-in-azure-functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39648697/how-do-i-delay-the-execution-of-an-azure-function-after-it-fails, found this also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#host-json. Take a look at visibilityTimeout property of the host.json

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@4c74356b41 has pointed out the right way. The [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#hostjson-settings) settings for queue is what you are looking for.

> visibilityTimeout is The time interval between retries when processing of a message fails 
>   maxDequeueCount is The number of times to try processing a message before moving it to the poison queue.

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "queues": {
            "visibilityTimeout" : "01:00:00",
            "maxDequeueCount": 2
        }
    }
}
```

If your function is v1, similarly

```
{
    "queues": {
      "visibilityTimeout" : "01:00:00",
      "maxDequeueCount": 2
    }
}
```

**Update**

Since the problem is mainly about changing `visibilityTimeout` according to specific situation, setting the delay of `CloudQueue.AddMessageAsync` accordingly is the only way. Actually the `visibilityTimeout` does exactly the same thing but on the function app level(all queue), so we don't need to insist on it in this case.

Comment: but it set one value for all queries, I want to set different value for every case

Comment: @OlegSh You mean in each case the delay of dequeue is different? If so we may have to rely on your own implementation code, the configuration is on the level of whole function app, which can't be changed dynamically.

Comment: yes, I need diferent delay in each case (i.e. in place, where internal server is not available, I want to retry in 1 hour, but in place, when local DB is not updated, in 5 minutes)

Comment: @OlegSh Hmm... I think set the delay of  `CloudQueue.AddMessageAsync` according to the situation is the only way.  Actually the `visibilityTimeout` does exactly the same thing but on the function app level(all queue), so we don't need to insist on it in this case.